# Proof using vectors.

Tags: vectors, triangles

If $Q$ is the point of intersection of medians of a triangle $\triangle ABC$ then show that $\vec{QA} + \vec{QB} + \vec{QC} = 0$

I am taking help from this link.

[If Q is the point of concurrence of the?](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101205031244AAESXyo)

But two problems first it is not well written and second its not involved use of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\vec{QA} + \vec{QB} + \vec{QC} = 0 \Leftrightarrow (\vec{A}-\vec{Q})+(\vec{B}-\vec{Q})+(\vec{C}-\vec{Q})=0 \Leftrightarrow \vec{Q}=\frac{\vec{A}+\vec{B}+\vec{C}}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the triangle be $\triangle ABC$. Its medians are $\vec{AA_1} = \frac 12 (\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}) $, $\vec{BB_1} = \frac 12 (\vec{BA}+\vec{BC}) $, and $\vec{CC_1} = \frac 12 (\vec{CB}+\vec{CA}) $.

Now from basic goemetry we know that the common point of all medians $Q$ splits the medians in relation $2:1$, on other words,
$\vec{AQ} = \frac 23 \vec{AA_1}$, $\vec{CQ} = \frac 23 \vec{CC_1}$, and $\vec{BQ} = \frac 23 \vec{BB_1}$.

Finally, $$\vec{QA} + \vec{QB} + \vec{QC} = - \frac23 (\vec{AA_1} + \vec{BB_1} + \vec{CC_1}) = -\frac 13(\vec{AB}+\vec{AC} + \vec{BA}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CB}+\vec{CA})=\vec 0. $$

Comment: Can you explain first step.

Comment: @JohnSr Parallelogramm rule of vector addition plus a basic fact that the point of intersection of parallelogramm diagonals splits them in half.

Comment: How you finded medians?

Comment: Can you send me the link of this property please.

Comment: If you have a parallelogram $XYZT$ with diagonals intersecting at a point $Q$, then the triangles $\triangle XQY$ and $\triangle ZQT$ are equal by a criterion "a side and two adjacent angles are the same for both triangles". This gives you immediately $XQ=QZ$ and $YQ=QT$.

Comment: You are confusing me question is here has a triangle you are taking the example of parallelogram. Your solution is clear except how you find medians.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\vec A$ for the position vector $\vec{OA}$. The median line $m_A$ through $A$ is then given by the parametrization
$$m_A:\quad t\mapsto (1-t)\>\vec A+t\>{\vec B+\vec C\over2}\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ .$$
Putting $t:={2\over3}$ here produces the point
$$\vec Q:={1\over3}\bigl(\vec A+\vec B+\vec C\bigr)\in m_A\ .$$
Due to symmetry this point will lie on all three medians, hence is the point of intersection of the medians. It follows that
$$\vec{QA}+\vec{QB}+\vec{QC}=(\vec A-\vec Q)+(\vec B-\vec Q)+(\vec C-\vec Q)=3\left({\vec A+\vec B+\vec C\over 3}-\vec Q\right)=\vec0\ .$$

Comment: Sir not understanding anything except last step.