# Proof of a property

Tags: vectors, triangles, median

[Taking refrence to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094566/proof-using-vectors)

One user is answering that -

In triangle ABC if $\vec{AA_1}$ median then

$\vec{AA_1} = \frac 12 (\vec{AB}+\vec{AC})$

I want to know **Is this really a property?**

If yes then what is its proof? Because I spent so much time to search but find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\vec{AK}=2\vec{AA_1}$
Then $ABKC$ are parallelogram. Thus
$$2\vec{AA_1}=\vec{AK}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BK}=\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}$$
Then $$\vec{AA_1}=\frac{\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}}2$$

#### Addition:

[image]

#### In generally:

If $$\frac{AM}{MB}=\frac mn$$
then
[image]

Comment: AK = AB+BK. How AB+BC?

Comment: No. It's $$|AK|=|AB|+BK$$

Comment: Then why you write BC in step 2?

Comment: For any point $B$ (may be $B \not \in AC$)
$$\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}=\vec{AC}$$

Comment: You are not understanding. AK = AB + BK. But you are writing AK = AB + BC.

Comment: And I know addition property.

Comment: Sorry! I edited!

Comment: One last question if two vectors are equal we can say that it is parallel?

Comment: @JohnSr:  Yes!!!!!